# Linear gradient border bottom does not work

Tags: css, linear-gradients, underline

I'm using the following code to give the double underline on my site (https://howtogetrippedathome.com/) below my widget titles a gradient color:

```
.widget-title:after {
    border-bottom: 6px double;
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff2828, #F27B26);
}
```

However, when I apply this code the underline dissapears. I have looked in other topics and this should work, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use multiple gradient like this

```css
h1{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to left,  red, blue),
   linear-gradient(to left,  red, blue); 
  background-size:100% 2px;
  background-position:bottom 0 left 0,bottom 5px left 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>some text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pseudo element(:after),
Try this directly:

```
.widget-title {
    border-bottom: 6px double;
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff2828, #F27B26);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But the underline just stays in one color now.

Answer (score 0):

In css3 please use pseudo-element with ::after instead of :after.
And please ensure you at least an empty content for the pseudo element style like (content: "") and specify display property.

```
.widget-title {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.widget-title::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #ffba10;
  border-bottom: 6px double;
}
```

Above code works as expected. Please refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) for more info.